# How to change background color of div when tapped on phonegap android

Tags: android, android-layout, jquery-mobile, cordova

I just want to know how to change the background of div when tapped on phonegap android.
I'm using jquery mobile also.

Thanks,
Bernard

Answer (score 0):

Try this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5kfnT/2/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        // Bind the tapHandler callback function to the tap event on div.box
        $( ".upload" ).on( 'vclick', tapHandler ); 
        // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'tap' class to it
        function tapHandler() {
            $(this).css('background','yellow');
        }
    });
});
```